# Curved menu with shadow hides sub menu

Tags: menu, shadow, submenu, curve

We want to apply a curved shadow line on our menu, at the bottom (see Image).
This shadow/curve must be in-front of the sub menu. So the shadow overlaps the sub menu. This is the problem, because when we hover to the sub menu the sub menu will disappear. 
This is because the wrapper got a higher Z-Index then the sub menu.

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 153px;
    background: url("/public/images/headerBackground.png") no-repeat center center;
}

#header .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -470px;
    z-index: inherit;
    pointer-events: all;
}

#navigation li ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        background-color: #c40b29;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 30px 18px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 30px 18px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.3);
        box-shadow:         0px 1px 30px 18px rgba(46, 50, 50, 0.3);
        float: left;
        width: 152px;
        height: 166px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: -2px;
}
```

For an image of the design we got:
http://s18.postimg.org/uiaf1waxl/Schermafbeelding_2014_03_17_om_16_10_26.png